# Copying symbolic links in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

What is the simplest way of copying symbolic links on the Mac?

A python or perl solution would be preferred, but any solution would be a help.

I am copying frameworks for an installation package, and need the links to be maintained

Comment: My apologies for being a python/perl developer who hadn't realised that cp would do the job so simply. However I believe the title does specifically state what I wanted to do

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As David mentioned, OS X is missing the handy -a option that gnu cp has.

However, if you use -R to do a recursive copy, then it will copy symlinks by default, so

```
cp -R source destination
```

ought to work.

Comment: OS X now do support the -a option

Answer (score 11):

The solution of *@brian d foy* used to be correct. Newer versions of macOS do support

```
cp -a
```

Comment: In macOS (High Sierra) `cp -a` does not preserve hard links only symbolic links.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can use [os.readlink](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.readlink) and [os.symlink](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.symlink) to perform this action. You should check if what you operate on is actually a symbolic link with [os.lstat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.lstat) and [stat.S_ISLNK](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISLNK)

```
import os, stat
if stat.S_ISLNK(os.lstat('foo').st_mode):
    src = os.readlink('source')
    os.symlink(src, 'destination')
```

You could do it with the [-R option of cp](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html). This works because cp by default does not follow symbolic links but barks at copying non-files without specifying -R which means recursion.

```
cp -R source destination
```

In python that would be with the [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

```
from subprocess import call
call(['cp', '-R', 'source', 'destination'])
```

Note that a [macosx alias](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/Aliases.html) is not a symbolic link and therefore symbolic link specific treatment will fail on it.

Comment: The macosx alias link above is dead

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged python, i asume you mean something like copytree(src, dst[, symlinks]). Real symlinks (created by ln -s) will be copied as on any unix system. But if you create an alias with the finder, you wont get a symlink, but an alias. The MacOS offers two types of links: unix type symlinks and aliases (see http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/Aliases.html).  These aliases are not treated as links by many tools - neither copytree as i know.

Comment: I tagged python because it was my preferred scripting language, but it turns out cp does the job quite simply, thanks